# Is it "le" or "les" when translating "the biceps/triceps"?

Tags: articles, pluriel, ambiguïté

From the dictionary, it looks like biceps and triceps get the "le" since they're masculine:

- https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english-french/triceps
- https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english-french/biceps

But sometimes they are referred to as plural:

- https://www.ericfavre.com/lifestyle/anatomie-les-biceps/

and sometimes singular:

- https://www.dravelnutrition.fr/blog/exercice-musculation/le-top-5-des-meilleurs-exercices-biceps-pour-des-bras-muscle

**In cases where we need to translate `the biceps`, is it both acceptable to translate it into `les/le biceps` since the plurality is ambiguous?** e.g.

| English | French | Singular / Plural |
| --- | --- | --- |
| the left and right biceps | les biceps gauche et droit | PL |
| the left biceps | le biceps gauche | SG |
| the right biceps | le biceps droit | SG |
| the biceps | les biceps / le biceps | PL / SG |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about these muscles in general, the singular is more common than the plural:

> ***Le** biceps **est** un muscle du membre supérieur fléchisseur qui provoque le rapprochement de l'avant-bras vers le bras.* [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_fl%C3%A9chisseur)

but it's not forbidden to write:

> ***Les** biceps **sont** des muscles des membres supérieurs fléchisseurs qui provoquent le rapprochement des avant-bras vers les bras.*

I guess that would be similar in English ("The biceps is..." / "The biceps are...")

However, as soon as more than one actual muscle is involved, you need to use the plural:

> *Ils « [poussent de la fonte](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pousser_de_la_fonte) » pour se muscler **les** biceps.* (not *"le" biceps*).